# Show that a complex sequence is convergent if and only if width of tail converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a complex sequence. Define the $n$-tail $A_n$ and its width $d_n$ as: $$A_n:=\{a_k:k>n,k\in\mathbb{N}\} \\ d_n:=\sup_{x,y\in A_n}|x-y|.$$
Show that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent if and only if $\{d_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero.

I am thinking I should somehow relate the above definitions to the definition of a Cauchy-sequence. intuitively it makes sense, but I am confused by the notation. Can anybody help me?

Comment: $d_n \to 0$ means exactly that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Notice that $$d_N= \sup_{n,m \ge N} |a_n-a_m|$$

Comment: Can I simply state that $x=a_n$ and $y=a_m$? It just seems like more of an intuitive argument than a formal one to me. Where do I use the fact that it's a complex sequence and the defintion of the tail?

Comment: The definition of the tail is exactly what allows you to make the substitution $x=a_n, y=a_m$. The fact that $a_n$ is complex allows you to say that Cauchy implies convergent ( because $\Bbb{C}$ is complete).

Comment: Is this a valid answer to the problem?

Assume that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and thus a Cauchy-sequence. For $\epsilon>0$ exists an $N$ such that $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ for $n,m\geq N$.
By defintion we have that $d_n:=\sup_{x,y\in A_n}|x-y|$. Since $x,y\in A_n$ we can substitute $x=a_n$ and $y=a_m$ and get $d_N:=\sup_{n,m\geq N}|a_n-a_m|$. We now have that $$|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \lim_{n,m\to\infty}d_N=0  \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=0$$ which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: This is basically correct, and indeed the converse follows the same arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I really appreciate it :) Is there a way to accept your answer when it is posted as a comment?